# Compile directive from another directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm currently adding the `ng-model-options` directive to a number of my input boxes to debounce.  My elements look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-model-options="{ debounce: { 'default': 200 } }" />
```

I would like to put this in a directive so:

1. My markup is less cumbersome.
2. I can control the debounce value in one place in case I want to change it.

I ultimately want the markup to look like this where it uses a `debounce` directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" debounce />
```

I've attempted to implement this directive like so:

```
app.directive('debounce', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr('ng-model-options', "{ debounce: { 'default': 200 } }");
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

It appears to result in the correct HTML, but the debounce is not doing anything.  What is wrong with my directive?

Comment: @PankajParkar: That doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you dont need to even access the element. you can set the options in the ngModel controller's `$options` property and set the necessary values like this:

```
ctrl.$options = {debounce:{default:300}, updateOnDefault: true};
```

Code:

```
.directive('debounce', ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var options = ctrl.$options || {};

        ctrl.$options = angular.extend(options, {
          debounce: {
            default: 300
          },
          updateOnDefault: true
        });

      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('debounce', ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',

      require: 'ngModel',
      replace: false,

      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var options = ctrl.$options || {};
        
        ctrl.$options = angular.extend(options || {}, {
          debounce: {
            default: 300
          },
          updateOnDefault: true
        });
        
       
      }
    }
  }
]).controller('test', function() {
  this.callMe = function() {
    console.log(this.search);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test as vm">

  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.search" debounce ng-change="vm.callMe()" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.search" ng-change="vm.callMe()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: { 'default': 200 } }" />{{vm.search}}
</div>
```

If you want to make it more configurable by accepting a debounce value as attribute then:

```
.directive('debounce', ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var options = ctrl.$options || {updateOnDefault: true};

        ctrl.$options = angular.extend(options, {
          debounce: {
            default:  +attrs.debounce || 300
          }
        });

      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: That's a really cute answer.. +1

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically adding directives to yourself isn't supported very well in Angular.  You're on the right track with compilation, however the `ng-model` directive has already been compiled at the point that you're doing this.

Since `ngModel` is documented to run at priority 1, you need to be both `terminal` and run at priority 2 at a minimum so that your `ng-model-options` gets linked at the appropriate time.

```
app.directive('debounce', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 2,
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(tElement) {
      tElement.attr('ng-model-options', "{ debounce: { 'default': 200 } }");

      return function (scope, element, attrs, controllers, transclude) {
        $compile(element, null, 2)(scope, {
          parentBoundTranscludeFn: transclude
        });
      };
    } 
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

For doing the same you need to add directive with higher `priority` to avoid compilation of other directive & which will have `terminal` option set to true. Which will indicate that no other directive when that directive is running then from that directive `remove` the directive attribute & add the `ng-model-options` to apply debounce change.

> Removal of `debounce` attribute is necessary to avoid infinite compile

**Directive**

```
app.directive('debounce', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1,
    terminal: true, 
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      //compile when scope is not linked to the DOM.
      element.attr('ng-model-options', "{ debounce: { 'default': 200 } }");
      element.removeAttr('debounce'); //this removal is necessary to avoid infinite compile
      var compile = $compile(element);
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var link = compile(scope);
      };
    } 
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Removal of `debounce` is not necessary if you restrict the max priority of what's linked as in my answer.  You should do that anyway in order to avoid linking higher priority directives multiple times.  This will also fail when lower priority directives use transclusion.

Comment: @dherman but mentioning higher priority directive will doesn't allow other directive to make transclusion..